# Shuffling 2D array of cards

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array of "Cards" and i need to shuffle this array in rows and columns.

my array is like this :

```
private CardType[,] card =
{
    {CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic2, CardType.Basic4 },
    {CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic2, CardType.Basic30 },
    {CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic10, CardType.Basic5 },
    {CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic20, CardType.Basic30 },
};
```

I need a method to shuffle card array in rows and columns.

Comment: Just an idea is to create another array with same dimensions and set on each element a priority which is random number. Then sort the card array, using the priorities.

Comment: What does it means "i need to shuffle this array in rows and columns"?

Comment: @xanatos It means that he wants to shuffle the cards. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Fisher-Yates algorithm:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(Random random, T[,] array)
{
    int lengthRow = array.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int i0 = i / lengthRow;
        int i1 = i % lengthRow;

        int j = random.Next(i + 1);
        int j0 = j / lengthRow;
        int j1 = j % lengthRow;

        T temp = array[i0, i1];
        array[i0, i1] = array[j0, j1];
        array[j0, j1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
CardType[,] cards =
{
    { CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic2, CardType.Basic4 },
    { CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic2, CardType.Basic30 },
    { CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic10, CardType.Basic5 },
    { CardType.Basic, CardType.Basic20, CardType.Basic30 },
};

Random rnd = new Random();
Shuffle(rnd, cards);
```

Note that you should try to reuse the `rnd`, and not recreate it!

Note how `array.Length` is the total `Length` of the array, X * Y, and how from a "global index" `i` we split it in a `i0`, `i1` (`x`, `y`) by dividing/doing the modulus with the length of a "row" (`lengthRow`).

Answer (score 1):

Using `class Random` generate a source-row and a dest-row, source-col and dest-col.

Exchange these two elements (if not identical)

Do this often.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard shuffle to do this. You just need to convert a single index into a row/column value, like so:

```
/// <summary>Used to shuffle collections.</summary>

public class Shuffler
{
    public Shuffler()
    {
        _rng = new Random();
    }

    /// <summary>Creates the shuffler with a specific random number generator.</summary>

    public Shuffler(Random rng)
    {
        _rng = rng;
    }

    /// <summary>Shuffles the specified array.</summary>

    public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
    {
        for (int n = array.Count; n > 1; )
        {
            int k = _rng.Next(n);
            --n;
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Shuffles the specified 2D array.</summary>

    public void Shuffle<T>(T[,] array)
    {
        int w = array.GetUpperBound(1)+1;

        for (int n = array.Length; n > 1; )
        {
            int k = _rng.Next(n);
            --n;

            int dr = n/w;
            int dc = n%w;
            int sr = k/w;
            int sc = k%w;

            T temp = array[dr,dc];
            array[dr,dc] = array[sr,sc];
            array[sr,sc] = temp;
        }
    }

    private readonly Random _rng;
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
int[,] array = new int[5, 7];
int w = array.GetUpperBound(1)+1;

// Fill array with 0, 1, 2, ... , 5*7-1

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
{
    int sr = i/w;
    int sc = i%w;

    array[sr, sc] = i;
}

var shuffler = new Shuffler();
shuffler.Shuffle(array);

Console.WriteLine(array[0,0]);
```