# Is it possible to move around in an array for new location?

Tags: c#

I am messing around and making a text based game, I am using an array as my layout for a map and I have a random starting point, and from that point I want to be able to move up down left and right but I am not sure how to proceed

```
int[,] dungeon = new int[5, 5] { {1,2,3,4,5}, 
                                 {6,7,8,9,10}, 
                                 {11,12,13,14,15}, 
                                 {16,17,18,19,20}, 
                                 {21,22,23,24,25}};
shuffleArray(dungeon);
int startingPoint;
// i think this has to be in the actual game loop for a new random spot?
for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        startingPoint = dungeon[i,j];
        Console.WriteLine(startingPoint);
        
    }  
}


void shuffleArray(int[,] arr)
{
    int n = arr.GetLength(0);
    int m = arr.GetLength(1);

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            swap(arr, i + rand.Next(n - i), j + rand.Next(m - j), i, j);
        }
    }

}
 void swap(int[,] arr, int changed, int changedB, int a, int b)
{

    int temp = arr[a, b];
    arr[a, b] = arr[changed, changedB];
    arr[changed, changedB] = temp;
   
}
```

Comment: _move up down left and right_ what's the desired output? Shuffle or something specific? https://stackoverflow.com/q/30164019/1315444

Comment: you use a 2d Array here so your startingpoint also needs 2 coordinates and cant be just an int. If you have an int pair as starting point (hint there is a Point class in the framework that you could missuse) Moving is just a matter of changing the correct value of that pair and checking your dungeon bounds. The values in dungeon you show are just examples right? They should not be somekind of index?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)` - how many times do you think this loop will iterate?

Comment: Btw. If you make that a 1-D Array, finding a random starting point is as simple as getting an integer from `Random`.

Comment: @Fildor for a 2-D array it is as simple as getting 2 integers from Random ;)

Comment: The goal is to have a starting point which I have already, and from that starting point to be able to move around. I am using an array because it seems like its best for a grid right now I only have a 5x5 grid

Comment: @MarkBaijens A single int is even enough for a 2D Array

Comment: @Fildor That's trickery! :D. My point was that it's not hard to do it with a 2-D array so no need to convert it.

Comment: @wanderingsabs So what exactly is the problem? To move up or down you increment or decrement Y and to move left or right you increment or decrement X ...

Comment: @MarkBaijens Depends. If you are used to it, neither is really _that_ hard. In this case OP seems to have a "board" in mind like a game board. So it is just convenient to express that thought in a 2D Array, while its handling comes with its own quirks.

Comment: After edit: So you have your game board and shuffle it. Then you make the upperleft corner your starting point. Always. Now what do you _want_ to do next? You have a random value "startingPoint" at coords (0|0). What now?

Answer (score 0):

Given a starting point (I'm calling it "position"), you can find the value in the shuffled array with this method:

```
// position is NOT zero-based! In a 5x5 matrix 1 is the first position
// and 25 is the last position
int getValueAtPosition(int position)
{
    //assuming non-jagged board!
    var w = dungeon.GetLength(0);

    int row = position % w == 0 ? (position / w) : (position / w) + 1;

    int col = position % w == 0 ? w : position - ((row - 1) * w);

    int location = dungeon[row - 1, col - 1];
    return location;
}
```

Now, if you move left you subtract one from the current position and pass it into this method. Likewise, add 1 to move right.

To move up or down subtract or add 5.

Be sure to check bounds so you don't move out of the matrix when adding or subtracting.